# Vertical scroll in storybook is not accurate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I'm trying to implement this react-dates example, in storybook, on my code:
http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DayPickerRangeController&selectedStory=vertical%20scrollable&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

It looks that the info that they show about the component props that they pass are not accurate:

[image]

It, is like is copy & paste from the previous examples.

So, storybook examples, 'vertical scrollable' & 'vertical scrollable with custom month nav' are using a different func  in order to load more months, it cant be '**onPrevMonthClick**' & '**onNextMonthClick**', that is shown on 'Show info' button.

How do I override the 'down arrow' so as to load more months or not?

Has anybody come upon that issue before?

Answer (score 1):

To override the prev/next buttons completely, the only way I see how is to pass your own buttons to `navPrev`/`navNext` with your own buttons that `stopPropagation` when you want to stop them from activating:

```
navNext={
  <button
    onClick={e => {
      const dontGoNext = true;
      if (dontGoNext) {
        // Stop propagation of button and prevent next month from loading
        e.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        // do nothing..
      }
    }}
  >
    Next
  </button>
}
```

You can checkout an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ry87wm8274

The reason this is the only way I see how to do it is because the navigation is tightly controlled with a click handler in `DayPickerRangeController` ([onNextMonthClick](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/a7dbbde3e7fc63bc8d27da305bd72699ecbce3ca/src/components/DayPickerRangeController.jsx#L716-L745)) that handles the ability to go to the next month view.

---

To *just disable the buttons* using the `DayPickerRangeController` you can set `minDate`/`maxDate` which in turn disables the prev/next buttons.

Those 2 props affect the `disablePrev`/`disableNext` props ([Github Lines](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/a7dbbde3e7fc63bc8d27da305bd72699ecbce3ca/src/components/DayPickerRangeController.jsx#L224-L225)) which are passed down through the `DayPicker` to the `DayPickerNavigation` component.

---

Note: These props **are not available** in the `DateRangePicker` component, because they are not passed down. Unsure as to why.

---

P.S. react-dates; docs aren't the best IMO. I always end up having to look at the source to understand how to do what I am wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks for our answer and your example, but as i mention on my question, i m using 'VERTICAL_SCROLLABLE',like the example: http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DayPickerRangeController&selectedStory=vertical%20scrollable&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

My question is, what is the function and how i override it, that loads more months, when you click the 'down arrow' on the bottom.

Comment: I'm sorry, I narrowed down my answer to _just_ being able to disable the buttons, I will update my answer and example to _override_ the buttons the only way that I see that they can be.

Comment: Do you see any way to get the number of displayed months on the scrollable calendar, so as to update the next button and disable 'dontGoNext' flag ?

Comment: You manually set that via the `numberOfMonths` prop :) So if you set `numberOfMonths={3}`, then 3 months will be displayed within the scrolling view.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a stylesheet

> storybook.scss

inside the **.storybook** folder and write below styles;

```
#storybook-docs{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

then import storybook.scss to preview.ts

```
import './storybook.scss';
```

It works prefect!